# How to disable apikey for local serverless development?

Tags: serverless, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I created a simple api (using [serverless](https://www.serverless.com/)) which is protected by an apikey (when deployed via `$ serverless deploy`). However, for local development (`$ serverless offline`) I do not want to use an api key. How can I disable this for local only?

This is my `serverless.yml`:

```
service: my-service
frameworkVersion: "3"

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs16.x
  region: eu-central-1
  apiGateway:
    apiKeys:
      - name: my-apikey
        value: ${ssm:my-apikey}

functions:
  myfunc:
    handler: src/v1/myfunc/index.get
    events:
      - http:
          path: /v1/myfunc
          method: get
          private: true

plugins:
  - serverless-esbuild
  - serverless-offline
  - serverless-dotenv-plugin
```

Note: I am aware that I could simply set `private: false` when doing local development but this is quite tedious when there is a long list of functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to use the `--noAuth` option:

```
serverless offline --noAuth
```